# Am I mishearing 这房子里究竟哪一样, and if not, how do I understand it?

Tags: meaning-in-context, listening

After moving to a new place, friends are visiting Lao Wang.  It turns out his wife has decided the curtains, carpet, etc.

> ……老王回答：“所有的家具都是我太太挑选的。”我终于忍不住问道：“**这房子里究竟哪一样**。是你挑选的呢？”老王思考了片刻，说：“我太太。”
> <sub>[HSK5 past exam H51224](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9CpQbb6IFs&t=1135s), questions 31 and 32</sub>

In this listening problem, I don't quite understand the nuance of the last question.  I'm not 100% sure I'm hearing it correctly.  I'm expecting this to be a joke of some kind.  It says something like:

> I finally couldn't help but ask: "This place is the same.  Did you choose it?"  Lao Wang thought for a bit and replied: "My wife."

This doesn't quite make sense to me.  I feel like I'm missing something, noting it's possible I misheard something.  (I was expecting a joke along the lines of "So, what about this place did you choose?"  "My wife.")

**Question**: Am I mishearing 这房子里究竟哪一样, and if not, how do I understand it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the period mark is a typo, the sentence only makes sense without it.

这房子里究竟哪一样。是你挑选的呢 (X)

这房子里究竟哪一样(東西)是你挑选的呢 (O) - What (thing) in the house was actually chosen by you?

The punchline is '我太太' (my wife) -- The only thing in the house that was chosen by him was his wife

Answer (score 4):

```
老王回答：“所有的家具都是我太太挑选的。”

我终于忍不住问道：“这房子里究竟哪一样，是你挑选的呢？”

老王思考了片刻，说：“我太太。”
```

My translation goes like this

```
Lao Wang replied: "All the furniture was my wife's decision." 

I finally couldn't help asking, "Is there anything in the house that was your decision?" 

Lao Wang thought for a moment and said, "My wife."
```